# TypeError at /email-signup Object of type 'WSGIRequest' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, django, python-requests, mailchimp

Currently trying to make an email newsletter work with django 2.2 and MailChimp.
Got the code from a youtube video, I thought I unterstood it, but then I faced the error in the title. 
I have tried various things such as just passing data=data in the subscribe function, but nothing I tried worked. The thing that concerns me is that it worked just fine in the video, and since it's not old I don't think that django has changed significantly.
Any help/explanation would be greatly appreciated.

**views.py** (not all imports)

```
from django.conf import settings
from .forms import EmailSignupForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
import json
import requests


MAILCHIMP_API_KEY = settings.MAILCHIMP_API_KEY
MAILCHIMP_DATA_CENTER = settings.MAILCHIMP_DATA_CENTER
MAILCHIMP_EMAIL_LIST_ID  = settings.MAILCHIMP_EMAIL_LIST_ID
api_url = 'https://{dc}.api.mailchimp.com/3.0'.format(dc=MAILCHIMP_DATA_CENTER)
members_endpoint = '{api_url}/lists/{list_id}/members'.format(
    api_url=api_url,
    list_id=MAILCHIMP_EMAIL_LIST_ID
)

def subscribe(email):
    data = {
        "email_address": email,
        "status": "subscribed",
    }
    print(data)
    print(data[])
    r = requests.post(
        members_endpoint,
        auth=("", MAILCHIMP_API_KEY),
        data=json.dumps(data), # I think the error is caused here
    )
    return r.status_code, r.json()


def email_list_signup(request):
    form = EmailSignupForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            email_signup_qs = Signup.objects.filter(email=form.instance.email)
            if email_signup_qs.exists():
                messages.info(request, "You are already subscribed")
            else:
                subscribe(form.instance.email)
                messages.success(request, "You have subscribed successfully!")
                form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))

class HomeView(ListView):
    template_name = "home.html"
    model = Post
    form_class=EmailSignupForm


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        form = EmailSignupForm()
        context['form'] = form
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.all().order_by('-published_date')[:5]
```

urls.py

```
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^email-signup$', views.subscribe,name="email-signup"),
]
```

**forms.py**

```
class EmailSignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        "type": "email",
        "name": "email",
        "id": "email",
        "placeholder": "Type your email address",
    }), label="")

    class Meta:
        model = Signup
        fields = ('email', )
```

the form in **home.html**

```
{% block emailsignup %}
<div class="enter_email sidebar_element">
    <p class="white">Get all new posts E-Mailed to you! No Ads, we promise.</p>
    <form class="form " method='GET' action="{% url 'blog:email-signup' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <!-- <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Your email" name="email"> -->
        {{ form }}
        <button method="POST" class="btn btn-primary w-100 my-3" type="submit">Enter</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

if any code is missing please let me know, 
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: use email_list_signup as view function in your url pattern not the subscribe.

Comment: @NaqibHakimi thank you for your suggestion, now the error does not appear anymore. However, the email isn't registered in the admin panel nor in MailChimp.

Comment: trace your function and see if subscribe(form.instance.email) is reachable and executed.

Comment: @NaqibHakimi after adding your suggestion, the subscribe function is not called, but the email_list_signup function is. If I use the subscribe function in the urls, it is called, the error occurs, and the email_list_signup is not called.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
The main thing was changing the form in the HTML itsself. After tracing the function calls as suggested, I was able to figure out that the subscribe function was not even called. I investigated and found out that my form had the "GET" instead of "POST" method. The url in the action attribute was right, but the button also had the method post, which I removed (dont know if that was necesarry, though).
Then I changed the url in urls.py into a path, which shouldnt make a difference, but is good practise in the newer django versions, I guess.
I also added an enctype="multipart/form-data" to the form, which, according to my tests, is not necessary.
So the final files will be:

form in **home.html**:

```
{% block emailsignup %}
<div class="enter_email sidebar_element">
    <p class="white">Get all new posts E-Mailed to you! No Ads, we promise.</p>
    <form class="form " method='POST' action="{% url 'blog:email-signup' %}" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <!-- <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Your email" name="email"> -->
        {{ form }}
        <button class="btn btn-primary w-100 my-3" type="submit">Enter</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**:

```
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('email-signup/', views.email_list_signup, name='email-signup'),
]
```

**views.py**:

```
from django.conf import settings
from .forms import EmailSignupForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
import json
import requests


MAILCHIMP_API_KEY = settings.MAILCHIMP_API_KEY
MAILCHIMP_DATA_CENTER = settings.MAILCHIMP_DATA_CENTER
MAILCHIMP_EMAIL_LIST_ID = settings.MAILCHIMP_EMAIL_LIST_ID

api_url = 'https://{dc}.api.mailchimp.com/3.0'.format(dc=MAILCHIMP_DATA_CENTER)
members_endpoint = '{api_url}/lists/{list_id}/members'.format(
    api_url=api_url,
    list_id=MAILCHIMP_EMAIL_LIST_ID
)


def subscribe(email):
    data = {
        "email_address": email,
        "status": "subscribed"
    }
    r = requests.post(
        members_endpoint,
        auth=("", MAILCHIMP_API_KEY),
        data=json.dumps(data)
    )
    return r.status_code, r.json()


def email_list_signup(request):
    form = EmailSignupForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            email_signup_qs = Signup.objects.filter(email=form.instance.email)
            if email_signup_qs.exists():
                messages.info(request, "You are already subscribed")
                print("in email_list_signup already subscribed.")
            else:
                subscribe(form.instance.email)
                messages.info(request, "You have been successfully subscribed.")
                print("in email_list_signup you have been subscribed")
                form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

The other files not mentioned again stay the same.
Thanks for helping guys